# Passing multiple parameters in an AngularJS route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to implement a angular route which should have multiple parameters. Here is an example of what I tried:

```
.when('/myRoute/paramA/:paramA/paramB/:paramB/paramC/:paramC', {
    templateUrl: 'abc.html',
    controller: 'pwrController as pwrCtrl'
});
```

Now the problem in this is that I need to always pass paramA in order to pass paramB. And paramA and paramB in order to pass paramC.

Is there any way in angular where I can pass paramA, paramB or paramC independently ?

Thanks. !

Comment: That is how routing works: The only way to get to a further nested param is to have the previous params.

Comment: What do you mean by independently? The way you have designed it states that your URL will have all the parameters in the URL..

Why can't it be done like '?paramA='paramA'&paramB='paramB'&paramC='paramC'

Comment: I agree with AnkitG, use the $location.search('paramA', paramA) service to set parameters before you load the new route and then you can read it with $location.search().paramA

Comment: Also, if you don't have paramA pass it anyways with something that defines it as empty, like null, undefined, 0, or define your own. That way, you will always pass it, but when you read it you will look for a specific value that means it is undefined

Answer (score 14, accepted):

inject `$location` into your controllers and use that instead of routeParams

```
var paramA = 'something';
$location.search('paramA', paramA); // write
// result http://localhost:3000/#/route/routeParam?paramA=something

$location.search() // read whole object
$location.search().paramA // read one parameter
// result 'something';
```

Comment: Credit really goes to @AnkitG, who was first to make the suggestion.