# How to get multiple parameters in AngularJS from a link

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get data from the link where I'm getting first name and last name. The code work just fine if I use one parameter that is #/firstName/{{firstName}} but when I try to add another parameter then it doesn't show anything. Please help.

My link in the template

```
<a href="#/firstName/{{firstName}}/lastName/{{lastName}}">Profile</a>
```

---

My Route Provider configuration

```
$routeProvider.
when('/firstName/:fn/lastName/:ln', {
    templateUrl: 'profile.php',
    controller: 'ProfileController'
})
```

---

My Controller

```
allControllers.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.firstName = $routeParams.fn;
  $scope.lastName = $routeParams.ln;
}]);
```

---

My View

```
Welcome, {{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}!
```

Comment: You can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896675/passing-multiple-parameters-in-an-angularjs-route

Comment: don't forget to inclide ngRouter module

Comment: should work fine. What is happening? Any errors? Create demo that replicates problem